# How to match public key is same or not

Tags: digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am using `crypto.signText()` and `CAPICOM` to sign some text.

so,now i am having is Base64Encoded signed text.

then I am using BouncyCastle to verify the signature. till this it is ok.

now what i want to do is,

when user login into system for 1st time i want to verify that signature and then store publicKey into database. And from next login, i want to match the publicKey strored into database against that user with the newly got signed Text.

if the public key in signed Text and one which is stored in db is same then only user is allow to login into system.

how to implement this? (I am using JAVA lang)

Answer (score 0):

First signatures are created using the private key, not the public key. Afterwards the signature can be verified using the public key. This is what you could do, use the public key from the database and verify the signature of the "signed text". In Java you usually do not need Bouncycastle anymore. The runtime already contains everything you need.

Example how to verify a signature:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep4.html

For avoiding replay attacks the "signed text" should contain system time and date or a monotone counter. Therefore the text should also be checked for It's content to be up-to-date.